Ed25519 key size
(I searched a lot, but still got something unclear)
After search, it says Ed25519 key size is 32 byte, for both private & public key.
But from my golang program I generate a key, and it converts to 128 hex string (without 0x prefix), which is 64 bytes I suppose.
Questions:

For the 64 bytes, is the first half 32 bytes private key, and second half 32 bytes public key ?
If I only got the private key (32 bytes), and lose the public key (32 bytes), can I derive the public key only from the private key (32 bytes)?


2-a. If not, then I think it's more proper to call the whole 64 bytes as private key, since that's the whole key, right?
2-b. If answer to 2 is no, and answer to 2-a is no, then what's the different between key and private key? I thought private key should be able to derive public key.


For 1, you're correct that both keys are 32 bytes and typically stored together. That's because of this problem. For 2, yes you can, but you should be storing them together anyway for the linked reason.

@samuel-lucas6 That pretty much answered my key question, though I didn't get into the details about the problem why store private & public key together, instead of just store private key.

In short, storing the two keys together is a mitigation against leaking the private key. Another mitigation is to always re-derive the public key from the private key.
